# Import 3D (*.stl) model with media9

Tags: pdftex, 3d, media9

I have seen that is possible to insert a 3d model (*.u3d) model inside a pdf. But I have some stl objects and I can't manage to insert them into a pdf. 
Does anyone know a way to insert a stl file into pdf using latex? Maybe is there another package that can do this?

I can not manually convert this files in *.u3d because there are to many and all my objects ca from a soft that gives me only stl.

Any idea is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You could try converting to `.u3d` with [MeshLab](http://www.meshlab.net/) which is open-source freeware and [supposedly has a command line interface](https://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/discussion/499533/thread/c266b0c3/) that can be used for batch processing. Note that I have not tried this myself.

Comment: This works but for me it will be great if I can just import a stl file.

Comment: No way. PRC and U3D are the supported formats. You need an external programme for generating these from other formats.