# Embedding *.stl models in the PDF

Tags: pdftex, 3d, media9

This question has been asked before about 5 years ago [Import 3D (*.stl) model with media9](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443398/import-3d-stl-model-with-media9)

My question is just related as a follow up to see if there was more to it.
I ask because, lately I am trying to import *.stl into the latex and it does not compile. Primarily because as stated the media9 library supports U3D and PRC file formats only, while the mesh is in STL.

So, what I end up doing is creating a placeholder in the tex/pdf for the STL file by passing a dummy U3D object. Then opening the compiled tex/pdf file in Acrobat 9 Pro and using the 3D Model tools and inserting the STL instead of the dummy U3D.

My question is, if Adobe can already handle the STL file within it, why am I unable to directly compile it through tex.

NOTE: This method would enable the 3D viewer in Adobe and some other PDF software's out there on Windows. And will not work in Linux machines.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Acrobat (Reader) still supports only embedded [U3D and PRC](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/supported-file-formats-acrobat-reader.html#main_Direct_file_conversion_formats__Acrobat__) formats for 3D objects. Acrobat 9 Pro was bundled with an import converter for [other 3D formats](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/supported-file-formats-acrobat-reader.html#main_2D_and_3D_formats__Acrobat_9_Pro_Extended__Adobe_3D_Reviewer_) than U3D and PRC. Newer Acrobat versions do not have it anymore.